# Pojection of a vector onto an axis

Tags: c++, matrix, graphics, collision-detection

I am trying to implement  collision detection system using the Standard Axis Theorem and from what I understand I need to construct an axis perpendicular to each edge of my model. Then I take each vertex from another model and project that onto the axis. I have found several different ways to do it and am not sure which one is correct. At the moment the way I am doing it is:

```
glm::vec2 AssetInstance::project(glm::vec3 axis)
{
    GLfloat min = glm::dot(axis, vertices[0]);
    GLfloat max = min;

    for(int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); i++)
    {
        GLfloat temp = glm::dot(axis, vertices[i]);
        if(temp < min) min = temp;
        else if(temp > max) max = temp;
    }
    //std::cout << min << " " << max << std::endl;
    return glm::vec2(min, max);
}
```

where `vertices` is a `std::vector`in my class `AssetInstance` that contains all of the vertices of that instance. I have implemented this into the rest of my collision-detection algorithm but my collisions don't seem to be registered at the right spot. Collisions are detected but the objects aren't touching yet (they are rather far apart). I am wondering if maybe I need to implement project differently? This method should find the minimum and maximum values for a series of vertices projected onto an axis.

Comment: Hi Thom. Three things: first, it's rather difficult to provide an answer for a code snipped of a complex code without providing further details. To increase your chances of getting a solution of another person I recommend to provide an example that is reproducible. Second, since the code can't be reproduced, once can not understand what exactly you mean by "they are rather far apart". Third, it would also help if you could post your results. It seems like an interesting question.

Comment: Two questions. You say `axis perpendicular to each edge`. There're an infinite number of vectors perpendicular to an edge, do you mean each face? What is the condition for collision, that the min-max values of the two models overlap along an axis ?